# Ranking rules for camelCase attributes

Tags: algolia

I'm building an Algolia index to search through user-created communities on my site.

Just like for subreddits, the name of the communities can't contain spaces and are therefore often written by users in camelCase.

Here is an example of an object in my index:

```json
{
  "name": "headphoneAdvice",
  "description": "This community is dedicated to enthusiasts and newcomers. We are all about making the right decision when purchasing new headphones."
}
```

Both `name` and `description` are set to be searchable attributes and i'm currently using these ranking rules :

```
["typo","geo","words","filters","proximity","attribute","exact","custom"]
```

However, this does not seem to work well with the camelCase `name`. For example, if I type `"advice"` in the search, the object above with `"name": "headphonesAdvice"` isn't found.

I'm guessing this is because words in camelCase are considered single words and thus do not match.

I've looked online for rules that allow indexing of camelCase attributes but couldn't find anything really.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, found that someone at algolia thought of this and added https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/camelCaseAttributes/ kudos!